# Get Mongodb Documents for a given time range in a date range

Tags: mongodb

I want to find out documents which exist between a certain time period for a given date range.

I have only a field  "date" which is stored as a Date object.

**For Example -**

Find all documents with time between 10:00 am to 23:30 pm for dates ranging from 10th Jan 2018 to 30th Jan 2018

( Also I am currently using Version 3.4)

Answer (score 3):

You can add temporary field which will represent minutes part of your date as 60*[$hour](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/hour/index.html) + [$minute](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/minute/index.html), so it will be 600 for 10 am for instance and then apply your filtering conditions:

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: {
            minutes: {
                $add: [ { $minute: "$date" }, { $multiply: [ { $hour: "$date" }, 60 ] }]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $match: {
            $and: [
                { "date": { $gte: ISODate("2018-01-10T10:00:00.000Z") } },
                { "date" : { $lte: ISODate("2018-01-30T23:30:00.000Z") } },
                { "minutes": { $gte: 60*10 } },
                { "minutes": { $lte: 23*60+30 } }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        $project: { minutes: 0 }
    }
])
```

Comment: Thanks. Works Perfectly !!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the following code.

```
db.getCollection('collection name').aggregate([
    {$project: {
        "yearMonthDayUTC": { $dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m-%d", date: "$date" }},
        "timewithOffset": { $dateToString: { format: "%H:%M:%S", date: "$date", timezone: "Your time zone" }}
        }
    },
    {$match: {
            "yearMonthDayUTC": {$gte: "2018-01-10", $lt: "2018-01-30"},
            "timewithOffset": {$gte: "10:00:00", $lt: "23:30:00"}
        }}
])
```